# How bash builtins works with pipeline

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

Bash [builtins defines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) as:

> The shell executes the command directly, without invoking another program.

And a pipeline like `foo | bar` works roughly like: `bar` waits inputs from `foo`, and `foo` exits first, and then `bar` exit.

In bash a pipeline like this works as expected:

```
$ history | grep curl
```

But how can `grep` manage to know `history` is done its work, and exits itself? Since `history`, which is a builtin, was not spawning new process. Does `history` generate an `EOF` signal or something?

Comment: the shell runs each command from a pipeline in a separate process, no matter if it's an external command or a built-in. So yes, `history | ...` is spawning a new process, even if it's just another instance of bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the manual says "without invoking another program", it means that the shell doesn't use `execve` to execute another programs. When a command uses redirection, the simple implementation is to `fork` another process and do the redirection for that process only, leaving the file descriptors of the parent shell unmodified. This is also what `bash` does with this command, as can be verified with `strace`.

It is possible to do some trickery and avoid the forks for internal commands, but it seems they are not used in this case.

The second program can't detect that the first program exits, it can only detect that the output side of the pipe has been closed (which may happen because the program exited, or because of a regular `close`). The reading side of the pipe will receive an EOF.

It is common but not necessary for the first program in a pipe to exit first. Consider:

```
sleep 10 | echo done
```

If the second program of the pipe exits before the first and the first tries to write to the pipe it will get the signal `SIGPIPE`, which will terminate the process, unless it is caught.

```
(sleep 10; echo test ) | echo done
```